# Error occurred while bundle install coffee script

Tags: ruby-on-rails

An error occurred while installing coffee-script-source (1.7.0), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.7.0'` succeeds before bundling.

After `gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.7.0'`

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Comment: What happens if you type `gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.7.0'`?

Comment: ERROR ...... You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.

Comment: Try "sudo gem install coffee-script-source -v '1.7.0'"

Comment: Try this sudo gem update --system and then try to install the gem

Answer (score 0):

I think I just solve it.

The entire information the terminal returns when asking me to input password was:

Your user account isn't allowed to install to the system Rubygems.
You can cancel this installation and run:

```
bundle install --path vendor/bundle
```

to install the gems into ./vendor/bundle/, or you can enter your password
and install the bundled gems to Rubygems using sudo.

I is the password method that doesn't work but things got fixed after typing `bundle install --path vendor/bundle`.